# Background CSS not showing up in IE9

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I tried these codes and for some reason the background is not showing up in IE9. Compatibility mode is off, it's running in IE9 mode. It works fine in IE 10, Chrome, and Firefox.

```
body {
  background : url('/img/fade.png') repeat-x,
  url('/img/fadeh.png') repeat-y,
  url('/img/bg.png') repeat,
  ;
}
```

Second try:

```
body {
  /*background-image: url(img/fade.png), url(img/fadeh.png), url(img/bg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat;*/
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: have you specified a doctype? and if so which one?

Comment: Isn't the comma just before the semicolon causing problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

ie9 breaks without a doctype with multiple background images

edit:

also try in your css

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have add `,` on the last background url.

Replace with this

```
body{
   background:url('/img/fade.png') repeat-x,
   url('/img/fadeh.png') repeat-y,
   url('/img/bg.png') repeat;
}
```

**Example jsFiddle DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/5p4GS/